# Map a button to a row in a table created using Flask (with Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm learning a bit of web programming (cs50) and I'm facing a problem which I can't find a solution to..

As a project, I'm writing a website which act as a Password Manager.
Backend is written in Python, using Flask.
I have a page which list all the passwords an user have saved in the database, it's displayed as a table like so :
(element[0] refer to the name of the password, element[1] to the password itself and element[2] to it's rowid (used to try to give unique id's))

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
            <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Password name</th>
                <th>Password</th>    
            </tr>

            <tbody>
            {% for element in codes %}
            <tr>
                <form action="" method="post" id="form{{ element[2] }}">
                    <td name="name"><b>{{ element[0] }}</b></td>
                    <td id="password{{ element[2] }}" name="password" class="hidetext">{{ element[1] }}</td>
                    <td id ="{{ element[2] }}">
                        <select class="form-control" name="option">
                            <option disabled selected value>Options :</option>
                            <option value="1">Reveal password</option>
                            <option value="2">Modify password</option>
                            <option value="3">Delete password</option>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="apply();">Confirm</button>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

So a row has 4 fields, the name, the passwords, a select menu, a button to apply the option chosen in the select menu.
The issues I'm encountering are mostly "How to access data of the row the user is interacting with". I tried to solve this using the DOM :
While on the website, in the console if I inspect the submit button, I can access all the data like so :

```
var row = $0.offsetParent;
var selection = $(row).previousElementSibling.value;
    if (selection == 1) {
        var pass = row.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
        $(pass).toggleClass('hidetext');
```

In my actual code, I replaced $0 by $(this) I thought it would do the trick but I'm obviously wrong.

To prevent the normal action of the button, I'm using this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').each(function(){
        $(this).submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  
        })
    })
})
```

And for the two others options, I have pretty much the same issue the console give the same error (TypeError) as the first one.

```
else if (selection == 2) {
        var formId = $(row).previousElementSibling.id;
        $('#form' + formId).attr('action', '/modify_saved')
        $(this).submit();
    }
else if (selection == 3) {
        var formId = $(row).previousElementSibling.id;
        $('#form' + formId).attr('action', '/delete_password')
        $(this).submit();
    }
else {
        return false;
    }
```

Sorry if this is a little all over the place, I'm trying to put everything in order as I'm writing this message :-)

Comment: Hi ,did you tried with `$(this).closest("form").submit()` and use click event on button itself ?